# How to programmatically read a mail message in iOS?

Tags: ios, email

I'm planning a new iOS application (MApp) which should be able to process selected mail messages from the iOS Mail client. 
The desired flow is as following: 
- Open the iOS mail
- Select a specific message
- "Send" it to the discussed MApp
- Get processed mail results from MApp

The only API related to emails I have found for iOS is [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller) but that's the other way arround. 
Is there an API in iOS to allow accessing (interactively, bound to user permission) a single mail message ?

Comment: You can't. The only possible way would be via a share extension, but iOS mail doesn't support share extensions.

Comment: That's what I was worried about

Comment: @Paulw11 do you know if Gmail allows us to read a single message?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't. The only way to actually get access to certain emails is to go through the email provider such as Gmail / Outlook and develop an app that interacts directly with the inbox. POP3 or something similar is also possible, but you have no easy way to actually get to the mail content itself.

Comment: do you know if it is possible to access email content(message) when interacting with Gmail?